# How do you exclude an element from a jQuery function that is included in the selector?

Tags: jquery

I am making a dropdown menu and am trying to make the list items image change from a plus (when not opened) to a minus (when opened).

The first Tier (parent list items) are set to `list-style:none;` so when the `.click()` below executes, I want the `.addClass('close');` to apply to everything EXCEPT the parent `<li>`'s...

The issue is, the selector used in the encompassing `.click()` function includes the parent list items.

What I need to do is say:

**"Apply the class 'close' to $(this) EXCEPT the first (parent) `<li>`'s'"**

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#nav li").click(function(event){

    // My attempt (not working)...
    $(this).not("#nav > ul > li").addClass('close');

    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children("ul").slideToggle(100);

    $(".last, a").click(function(event){
      event.stopPropagation();
    });

  });

});
```

And the **jsFiddle**:

[Click to View](http://jsfiddle.net/hExC3/1/)

So my attempt was the following:

```
$(this).not("#nav > ul > li").addClass('close');
```

That didn't work... So if anyone has any advice, it would be greatly appreciated! thanks :)

**Update:**

The class 'close' needed `!important` added to it. The jQuery was doing what it should. I will post an answer when I successfully remove the class upon closing the menu item.

**Update (2):**

Removed `!important` and changed class specification to `#nav li.close`. Thanks Adeneo!

**Update (3):**

Changed `.addClass()` to `.toggleClass()`. Seems to make this menu do what I wanted it to :) Thanks Sushanth -- for this suggestion!

Comment: It seems to be working. The `close` class is not applied to the top level `li`s

Comment: Added !important to the 'close' class and it applied the '-' list-style-image. Now I just need to remove the class upon closing the element...

Comment: @Asad - I just realized my CSS was the issue, not the jQuery... Needed the !important in the close class.

Comment: You're problem is css being more specific with an ID, you just need to be more specific, like #nav li.close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not being specific enough with the css selector.

using `#nav li` is more specific than just `.close`, to fix the problem use `#nav li.close` (not !important) :

```
#nav li.close {
    list-style-image:url(http://www.horsepowerfreaks.com/images/close.gif);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hExC3/3/)

Here's a little more on [CSS specificity and inheritance](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/)

Comment: Very cool. I didn't realize that would be any different than just specifying .close. Always used !important in the past. Cool!

Comment: Updated jsFiddle to include this change

Comment: If you know the inheritance and specificity rules, you really don't need to use !important or z-index to fix faulty CSS, so you should learn how it works, atleast enough to know when specificity is a problem, like in this case.

Comment: Well I thought I knew the ins and outs (been doing this for ten years lol) but yeah, I didn't know this particular gem of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.toggleClass()`

```
$(this).not("#nav > ul > li").toggleClass('close');
```

Assuming you are not adding/removing your class anywhere else in your code

Comment: Just remember to make sure you're not changing the class anywhere else, otherwise `slideToggle` and `toggleClass` could end up out of sync.

Comment: Beautiful! Seems to do the trick. Will update jsFiddle to use this! Thanks :)

Comment: @derekmx271 You do not need to progressively update the question as answers come in, otherwise it is difficult for future users to identify what the original problem was.